# Excel VBA - Import or copy columns to another workbook in a different order

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am trying to import an excel file having headers as A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, B2, C2, D2, A3, B3, ...D4 and each of the headers having data for 150 rows. I have to import this data set to another workbook but in the order:
A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4,....D4

Comment: Open the file and copy the columns to a new workbook/worksheet in the order you want them.

Comment: But the data file is huge, I have just given an example. the actual file can have 15 such columns 200+ rows of data. I wanted to write a macro to do this.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing that macro? Have you tried recording a macro while doing part of the task and then editing the output?

Comment: Is the pattern in which the columns should be rearranged just an example? I'm pretty sure, that this can be done by a vba macro. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by doing a custom sort.

```
Home Tab >> Sort & Filter >> Custom Sort >> Options
```

Then change the sort from "Sort top to bottom" to "Sort left to right".  Then its just a matter of selecting which row and how you want to sort it.